# Upload a file to folder in a document libary

Tags: document-library, folder, file

I have a java program that uploads a file to a document libary and i have a method that creates a folder. I want the file to be uploaded to the folder but i keeps getting uploaded outside the folder.

If i call the create folder method before the upload file method I get http 403 Forbidden error 
what could be the problem?

```
 public void createFolder(String digest) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                "http://industrial-ex/sites/tifdemo/_api/Web/Folders/add('enovia/newfolder')");


        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        request.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", digest);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, request, context);
        response.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        System.out.println("STATUS CODE Post Folder: " + response.getStatusLine());

    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code so we know how you're doing it.

Comment: i have added the method that creates the folder

Comment: is there a header missing?

Comment: That ain't my account

Comment: It's a friend not me lol :)

Comment: and btw @JussiPalo we do not ask the same question..

Comment: Is the problem 403 forbidden or file getting uploaded outside folder? Maybe we discuss the 403 forbidden at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136461/access-token-java and file outside folder in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot test this, but would using CredentialsProvider help, assuming you're using NTLM authentication.

```
public void createFolder(String digest) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
          "http://industrial-ex/sites/tifdemo/_api/Web/Folders/add('enovia/newfolder')");

    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    request.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", digest);

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
    new NTCredentials("username", "pwd", "", "domain"));
    List<string> authtypes = new ArrayList<string>();
    authtypes.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.TARGET_AUTH_PREF,authtypes);

    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, credsProvider);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request, localContext);

    response.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    System.out.println("STATUS CODE Post Folder: " + response.getStatusLine());
}
```