# Access Token (Java)

Tags: web-services, rest, access, token

How do you get `Access Token` using REST?

I'm trying to upload a folder in my Document Library using REST but it requires a `Access Token` in the header.

Here is the code:

```
 public void createFolder(String digest) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
            "http://industrial-ex/sites/tifdemo/_api/Web/Folders/add('enovia/newfolder')");

    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    request.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", digest);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, request, context);
    response.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    System.out.println("STATUS CODE Post Folder: " + response.getStatusLine());

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Flagged this as being posted by "a friend" here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136457/upload-a-file-to-folder-in-a-document-libary