# Sharepoint integration using java program

Tags: integration, java-api

We are trying to connect to Sharepoint 2013 using rest based api using a java program. Our code is -

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<String> authpref = new ArrayList<String>();
authpref.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
// httpclient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.CREDENTIAL_CHARSET,
// authpref);
NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials(userName, password, "portal", "xyz.com");
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

HttpHost target = new HttpHost("portal.xyz.com", 80);

// Make sure the same context is used to execute logically related
// requests
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

// Execute a cheap method first. This will trigger NTLM authentication
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://portal.xyz.com/Sites/XYZteam/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Sites/XYZteam/GlobalBrandBook')/Files");
httpget.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
httpget.addHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "GET");
httpget.addHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.01;+Windows+NT+5.0");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

We also tried  basic authentication/ Invoking SOAP Based Services but every time we keep getting 403 Forbidden error.
Any clues will be of great help.
Tina

Comment: We understand you're having issues, but posting essentially the same question 3 times does not help. Instead, pretty please, stick with the first question. 1st: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136457/upload-a-file-to-folder-in-a-document-libary, 2nd (already closed as duplicate): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136461/access-token-java

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am no way related to the person who has posted that question. And I didnt know there was a question posted like that. Secondly the solution you proposed dont work for me. I still get 403 error. Is there anything that we need to do on sharepoint side which can help me in fixing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Tried it already but didnt work.
What worked for me is this - http://www.muneebahmad.com/index.php/archives/127

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

public class NtlmTest01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String urlStr = “http://example.com/root/action.dll?p1=value1″;
        String domain = “”; // May also be referred as realm
        String userName = “CHANGE_ME”;
        String password = “CHANGE_ME”;      

        String responseText = getAuthenticatedResponse(urlStr, domain, userName, password);

        System.out.println(”response: ” + responseText);
    }

    private static String getAuthenticatedResponse(final String urlStr, final String domain, final String userName, final String password) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(domain + “\\” + userName, password.toCharArray());
            }
        });

        URL urlRequest = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlRequest.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod(”GET”);

        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String str = “”;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(str);
        }
        in.close();     

        return response.toString();
    }

}
```

Notest: NTLM Handshack
————————————————

GET
401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
————————————————

GET
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAA7IAAAoACgApAAAACQAJACAAAABMSUdIVENJVFlVUlNBLU1JTk9S

401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAAAAAACgAAAABggAAU3J2Tm9uY2UAAAAAAAAAAA==
————————————————

GET
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHIAAAAYABgAigAAABQAFABAAAAADAAMAFQAAAASABIAYAAAAAAAAACiAAAAAYIAAFUAUgBTAEEALQBNAEkATgBPAFIAWgBhAHAAaABvAGQATABJAEcASABUAEMASQBUAFkArYfKbe/jRoW5xDxHeoxC1gBmfWiS5+iX4OAN4xBKG/IFPwfH3agtPEia6YnhsADT

200 Ok

————————————————

Ref: http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me

```
    httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials(username, password, "", ""));
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost(host, 80, "http");

    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
```